# How to download my facebook group content?

Tags: facebook, download

I administer a facebook group of close friends and I'd like to backup all the data from it, including posts, user comments to those posts, likes, etc.

Is that possible? I'm very stupid regarding programming. The only thing I've found was this http://community.nextanalytics.com/articles/2012/05/easily-download-facebook-wall-posts-and-comments/

Thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: See: [Accessing & Downloading Your Information](https://www.facebook.com/help/1701730696756992).